# TypeScript type for reduce (...arg)

Tags: typescript

How to properly format Type of `...arg` ?

I seem to have exhausted all resources to try to solved the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'string'.

147  acc[label] = (...args) => css`
     ~~~~~~~~~~
```

As a result, I get the additional error from within my styled-component sheet when building my styles:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.

65     ${mediaQueries.tablet`
```

Here is the complete shortened code:

```
import {css} from 'styled-components'

interface MediaQueryProps {
    [key: string]: string;
}
  
const size: MediaQueryProps = {
    mobile: 'only screen and (max-width: 667px)',
    tablet: 'only screen and (min-width: 668px)',
} as const

const mediaQueryKeys = Object.keys(size) as Array<keyof typeof size>;

const mediaQueries = mediaQueryKeys.reduce((acc, label) => {
    acc[label] = (...args) => css`
        @media ${size[label]} {
            ${css(...args)};
        }
    `
    return acc
}, {} as Record<`${keyof typeof size}`, string>);

export default mediaQueries


// In App.js
import mediaQueries from './mediaQueries'

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    ${mediaQueries.mobile`
    background-color:black;
  `}
`
```

Has anyone run into this problem before or point me toward a solution?

Comment: What is `css`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wj4Q2m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: What type do you expect `mediaQueries` to be?  Is it supposed to be `Record<keyof typeof size, string`, an object holding strings, or  `Record<keyof typeof size, (...args: any[]) => string>`, and object holding *functions*?  If it's the former then your implementation is wrong (depending on what `css` is, I guess); if it's the latter then your type assertion is wrong.  When you fix your code to be a [mre], can you show a sample use of `mediaQueries`?

Comment: Sorry @jcalz ,I should have mentioned the `css` import from `styled-components` I expect mediaQuerries to be an `object` with existing keys of the `MediaQueryProps`.

Comment: Please address all errors [in this code](https://tsplay.dev/WG6RKm) which are not part of your question; that will help focus people on your actual problem instead of extraneous things (implicit `any` params, unimported/undeclared types).  Ideally you wouldn't keep any references to libraries unless you need help with them specifically (and you'd add a tag for it).  The point of example code is to be a self-contained demonstration of the issue and *only* that issue, or you risk distracting from the problem.

Comment: Ah, I was asking what property *values* the object holds, not its keys.  Are the values supposed to be strings (I suspect not, but that's what you said with `Record<..., string>`) or functions (I suspect so, if you are trying to *call* `mediaQueries.mobile` as a tagged template literal).  If it's functions, you want `{} as Record<..., XXX>` where `XXX` is the type of the actual function values that object is holding.  But that type is something you need to spell out or compute.

Comment: @jcalz, I've updated [the code above](tinyurl.com/paexh2fj), and this is precisely the issue i'm facing trying to convert this javascript to typescript.

Comment: Yes, the output should be a tagged template literal.

Comment: I wish this weren't so dependent on `css`, but I would probably do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDz28W) or something like it.  I think you should either remove the external dependency of your example code in the question (and replace it with some example tagged template literal function of your own making), or tag the question with `styled-components` so that you maybe get some expert eyes on it.  Right now I'm not comfortable answering if there's a strong dependency on the particulars of `css`'s typings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jcalz, this is the right answer! I guess I didn't know what Type to set the css attribute, and setting as `Parameters<typeof css>`.

**Solution:**

```
import { css } from 'styled-components'


const sizes = {
    mobile: 'only screen and (max-width: 667px)',
    tablet: 'only screen and (min-width: 668px)',
} as const


const mediaQueries = (Object.keys(sizes) as Array<keyof typeof sizes>).reduce((accumulator, label) => {
    accumulator[label] = ((...args: Parameters<typeof css>) => css`
        @media ${sizes[label]} {
            ${css(...args)};
        } 
    `) as typeof css
    return accumulator
}, {} as Record<keyof typeof sizes, typeof css>)



mediaQueries.mobile`
    background-color:black;
  `
```